# "based on" or "due to"

Tags: phrase-request

I have two methods. Each one of them, due to its main idea, requires a specific type of estimation strategy. I would like to say that using a correct English sentence.

> The estimation strategy of method A is strategy 1, while it is strategy 2 in method B, due to the main idea of each method.

or

> The estimation strategy of method A is strategy 1, while it is strategy 2 in method B, based on the main idea of each method.

Which one explains my point of view correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to convey two pieces of information, it may be better two split that sentence into two sentence. The first piece of information being that there are different estimation strategies in accordance to the main idea. The second piece of information being that method A's estimation strategy is strategy 1, and method B's estimation strategy is strategy 2.

Also, while stating the estimation strategy of each method, it is good to keep the same structure. So, instead of saying 
"The estimation strategy of method A is strategy 1, while it is strategy 2 in method B," it is better to say "The estimation strategy of method A is strategy 1, while the estimation strategy B is strategy 2." So, the order of the sentence is the same, the method being mentioned first and the strategy second.